# Can PHP detect an incomplete xmlhttprequest.send(data) command?

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm seeing error logs caused by what appears to be truncation of the post data. After debugging, my guess is that the issue is that we're using an xmlhttprequest to do the post, and the user is closing the browser before the entirety of the post data has been sent.

Here's our js code:

```
httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpReq.open("POST", url,false);
httpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
httpReq.send(param);
```

Is there a way to detect an incomplete send on the PHP side other than finding out there are missing post parameters? (Which we can't do since they're dynamic.)

**2011-02-27 Edit:**

As an example, the client is sending something like:

```
&obj1_name=Greeting&obj1_type=string&obj1_value=hello&obj1_id=34
```

The obj1_id is a required field in order to store the remaining details about the object. But sometimes we receive a string like:

```
&obj1_name=Greeting&obj1_type=string
```

My goal is to tell the difference between a broken client (one where it *meant* to send the short string) that we need to fix, and a working client that was closed too early (one where it *meant* to send the long string) and we can write off the error as unavoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized we simply need more info from the client in order to do this.
To accomplish this, we've added a known termination value on the client end. If that final parameter isn't set when the server sees it, it was an incomplete submission.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this function: [`connection_aborted`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php).
This approach will only work if you set `ignore_user_abort(true)`.
The script will now continue to run even if the user hit the abort button.
You then have to check the connection_aborted function and discard the data if necessary.

Another approach would be to save some kind of flag at the end of the script to mark the data as completely processed. If that flag is not set, you can discard the data.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That doesn't seem to work. I added:


    ob_implicit_flush();
    if(connection_aborted())
    {
      $strContents .= '!!!Connection Aborted!!!';
    }


But we never get that comment in the logs.

Comment: Try additionally to call `ignore_user_abort(true)` so that the script still runs when the client aborts and has a chance to write to the log.

Comment: The problem is that I _want_ to abort the script. It is currently running as if nothing went wrong, and causing crashes due to the incomplete data.

Comment: I can't set a flag as I am not aware of how much data the client is attempting to send, or where it may stop. The symptom of it stopping early is that within that data, certain sets of it are required for others, and those required pieces are sometimes the ones that are lost.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought so, as PHP is server-side and XmlHttpRequests are client-side.